# react helmet meta description not working, after initial it on my page component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-helmet

react helmet meta description not working? when I test on this site. https://metatags.io/

how do i make it appear, its empty even thou I initialize it on my page component. my title works but not the description.

```
  <Helmet>
      <title>{data?.name}</title>
      <link rel="canonical" href={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${slug}`}/> 
      <meta name="description" content={`${data?.name} Page`} />
      <meta name="keywords" content={`
        ${data?.name}, 
        ${data?.genres.toString().replaceAll(',', ', ')},
        ${data?.platforms.toString().replaceAll(',', ', ')}
        , game`}>  
      </meta>
  </Helmet>
```